# Must tokens be whitespace-separated in listings package?

Tags: listings

I'm using the listings package with a custom language definition. In my language, I have types of the form:

```
Foo@Bar>>Baz
```

Bar and Baz are keywords in the language and should therefore be highlighted. Foo is an arbitrary identifier and needs no special highlighting treatment.

If I separate the above tokens with whitespace, everything is fine. But if I do not separate them with whitespace (as in the above example), I only get appropriate highlighting for Baz, not for Bar.

I've looked at the documentation (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf), but haven't found a way to specify that the @ sign should not be part of the identifier. I tried including @ as a keyword:

```latex
keywords=[5]{@},
keywordstyle=[5]\bfseries,
```

but that didn't seem to help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind — I found the answer! The trick is to denote @ as an "other" character; by default, it is a "letter" and therefore included in identifiers. This suffices:

```latex
    alsoother={@},
```